# How to stop a DDoS attack using the CSF firewall?

Tags: security, apache-http-server, firewall

I have a local CentOS server used for web hosting. There are a lot of attacks that come in from many different IP addresses that try to hack into a Joomla 2.5 based website. This causes my Apache server to reach the MaxClients limit and send SIGKILL signal to all it's child processes.

This brings down the web server completely. I have installed CSF firewall and tried the PORTFLOOD setting, but it did not help even a bit. How may I stop the DDoS attack?

Apache version:  Apache/2.2.15

Comment: There is very little single person or small company can do to stop DDOS. If you do not have big money to spend on hardware or you need immediate help, use services provided by cloudflare or similar. They have sophisticated solutions to handle large volume of connections.

Comment: well yes but he could still limit the amount of connection though, he said its a blog so limiting connection isnt much a problem @mnmnc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should always do a google search before asking, Google is always your friend.
[Heres](http://anandarajpandey.com/2014/04/21/how-to-prevent-ddos-attack-by-csf-firewall/) a simple tutorial that shows u how to do it

Comment: I have tried this. Let's see if it works.

Comment: Why does superuser say that I should avoid thanking you???

Comment: what the what ?
and why did u down vote ?

Comment: No I did not downvote, Even if I wanted to I need reputation for that.

Comment: I had a chat with the developer. It seems that Joomla admin account has been hacked. We took necessary steps including admin password reset and used a strong password this time.

Comment: @melvincv Oh Ok :)), Choose it as a Accepted Answer or Delete the Question Anyways ...